# How to do a custom button like in the picture (Android app facebook)

Tags: android, button, social-networking

i have a little design problem with the app that i'm developping, i'm trying to create a social Android app and in the list of feed i'm trying to have the button comment and like like in this picture :

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZWpN.png)

I hope someone did it before and can guide me . Thanks

this is the custom button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                     android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="3dp" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
```

And this is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear"

    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_padding_left_right" >

        <circleview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_img"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
             >
        </circleview.CircleImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_profile_info_padd" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_profile_name"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:textColorLink="@color/link" />



    <com.example.mahdi.chat.FeedImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:text="Like"

            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#a0a3a7"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_like_comment"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/like"
            android:drawablePadding="-60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:text="Comment"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_like_comment"
            android:textColor="#a0a3a7"
            android:drawablePadding="-35dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/comment"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/like"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nbr_likes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="200 Likes"
            android:textColor="#a0a3a7"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nbr_comments"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nbr_comments"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/like"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/like" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nbr_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100 Comments"
            android:textColor="#a0a3a7"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nbr_likes"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nbr_likes"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add your existing layout xml file to look what you're doing wrong

Comment: Your picture is of a browser, i.e. HTML, not an Android layout.

Comment: I know but i saw the same in android too .

Comment: You can create any layout for the button. Then in the code inflate the layout where you want to place it, fill with data (image, text) and set onClickListener for the inflated layout.

Comment: What have the code java to do with the design ? can you please explain to me . Thanks